# .click() from an object property on appended buttons in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoshop

I'm making several buttons from an object and append them to the only div in the body: #main, everything works fine except for actual click function: I can't seem to make the buttons alert different properties.

This is my object:

```
var BrushDesc = function (n, i, t) {
    this.presetName = n;
    this.elemId = i;
    this.preset = t;
};
var brush = {};
brush.circ = new BrushDesc("circle", "circle", "basic circle");
brush.rect = new BrushDesc("rectangle", "rect", "19-2");
brush.softy = new BrushDesc("round soft", "softy", "softy");
brush.rake = new BrushDesc("|||", "rake", "21-3");
```

that was my first attempt appending the buttons but this always alerts last `.preset` property of the object:

```
for (var i in brush) {
    $('<button id="'+brush[i].elemId+'">'+brush[i].presetName+'</button>')
    .appendTo("#main")
    .click(function() {alert(brush[i].preset)}); 
}
```

So I thought 'okay :('. Then I made it differently and this seems to work but in the same time this looks really wrong (mostly because this relies on `.elemId` and `brush.property` having the same name:

```
for (var i in brush) {
    $('<button id="'+brush[i].elemId+'" class="main">'+brush[i].presetName+'</button>')
    .appendTo("#main")
}

$(".main").click(function() {
    var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");
    for (var i in brush) {
        if (brush[i].elemId == buttonId) alert(brush[i].preset)
    }
});
```

Can anyone please make it right?

**edit:** Thanks for pointing the Closures thread (haven't used them yet) Felix, but I'm not sure I understand how to apply this to my objects

```
var tps = [];
function createTps(i) {return function() {alert(br[i].preset)}} //doh
for (i = 0; i<5; i++) {tps[i] = createTps(i)} //but I should have keys here, not numbers?

var j = 0;
for (var i in br) {
    $('<button id="' + br[i].elemId + '" class="main">' + br[i].presetName + '</button>')
    .appendTo("#main")
    .click(function() {tps[j](); j++}); //yeah, sure
}
```

**edit2** Actually a friend of mine suggested to use Immediately-Invoked Function Expression instead of closure and it worked perfectly

```
for (var i in brush) {
    (function (i) {
        $('<button id="'+brush[i].elemId+'">'+brush[i].presetName+'</button>')
        .appendTo("#main")
        .click(function() {alert(brush[i].preset)});
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy - this is not an issue of event delegation. It's something else. please consider opening it.